# Where can I find GIS Data for Environmental Constraints for Hawaii?

Tags: data

I am looking for all the types of environmental constraints in shapefile format for Hawaii. Is there any environmental agency website or other source where I could find it? Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is Huwaii different from Hawaii?

Comment: And what is an environmental "constraint"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of data layers available at the [Hawaii State GIS Program](http://www.state.hi.us/dbedt/gis/index.html) website. Follow the GIS Data link. If environmental constraint means protected areas, reserves, there are several layers that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I meant by Environmental Constraints.